Firebase FCM push notification is not working on ios for Golang
I'm sending a message like this for Golang to send notifications via all platforms,
for _, receiver := range receivers {
    msg := &messaging.Message {
        Notification: &messaging.Notification{
            Title:    title,
            Body:     msgBody,
            ImageURL: imageURL,
        },
        Token: receiver,
        },
    },
}

And, then, sending the message through this:
type Client interface {
    PostMessages(messages []*messaging.Message) (error, *messaging.BatchResponse)
}

type client struct {
    fcmClient *messaging.Client
}

func newClient(configJson datatypes.JSON) (Client, error) {
    opts := []option.ClientOption{option.WithCredentialsJSON(configJson)}

    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    fcmClient, err := app.Messaging(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &client{
        fcmClient: fcmClient,
    }, nil
}

func (c *client) PostMessages(messages []*messaging.Message) (error, *messaging.BatchResponse) {
    resp, err := c.fcmClient.SendEach(context.Background(), messages)
    if err != nil {
        return err, resp
    }

    return nil, resp
}

It works fine for Android but not with the iOS device tokens!
I've also tried setting the Message with the APNSConfig and AndroidConfig configs but it did not help, and works well for Android but not for iOS.
Also tried other sending methods like SendMulticast using MulticastMessage.
